# show view XPages all entries as Notes Client

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I would expand the ViewPanel classic control of Xpages... so that when you scroll in the last entries the Notesview..in background with an ajax xhrGet the browser load other entries (
(the effect is the same of active stream of facebook....when you scrool in the end of page load other entries of stream)

In my scenario, I have different view of many type (with one categorize, two categorize, categorized with response..etc..) so that is good the ViewPanel for the users, but I would expand the functionality of classic ViewPanel control with this.

Anyone have idea/suggest for realize this feature?

I have test the "pagerSizes" control of Extension Library..but when you have much entries of view if very slow to render the entry (is normal because the browser need to render in one time much MB of data)

Tnx to all for any suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add a pager from extlib and set your repeat/view source

xe:pagerAddRows id="pagerAddRows1">

1. Add jquery to you xpage
2. add the following code to a client side scriptlibrary and add that scriptlibrary to your xpage

   $(function(){
       $(window).scroll(function(){
             if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                 $("[id$='pagerAddRows1_ar']").click();
             }
       });
   })

You can see it in action in the news stream at http://demo.intrapages.com 
when you scroll to the bottom of the screen the pager is clicked automatically and the new rows are fetched dynamically

Comment: Hi Adrian, thx very much for this suggest...but seem that the Extension Library control pagerAddRows don't work with a viewPanel but only with repeat and dataTable :-(

Comment: Adrian txn work! I need to set at TRUE the proprierty refreshPage of the control pageAddRow!